# I need to add my shortcode on SEO meta title

Tags: shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I need to add my shortcode which used to display U.S state names. I want same shortcode to display it on SEO meta title. Is it possible add my shortcode on meta title???

I'm using All in one SEO plugin free version.

Below is my shortcode function to display State names

function mp_usstate_name_shortcode() {

```
        $usstate_name = "";
        $chosen_state = [];
        global $STATES_ARRAY;
        $state = array_filter($STATES_ARRAY, function($state) {
            return $state["slugCode"] === get_query_var("usstate");
        });

       if(count($state) > 0){
        $chosen_state = array_pop($state);
        if(!empty($chosen_state) ){ 
            $usstate_name = $chosen_state["name"]; 
        }
      }
        return $usstate_name;
    }
```